# Downloaded Songs Don't Show Up In Xbox Music

Tags: music, xbox-music

As my title says.  Downloaded songs doesn't show up in all songs. After reset it works properly but after a month .same thing happens. Please help

Comment: Where are you downloading the songs from? The internet? Xbox Music? Somewhere else?

Comment: If you downloaded songs from illegal sites I mean if your songs are pirated then there is nothing you can do...............please download the song from XBOX Store...........

Answer (score 1):

Launch Xbox Music, tap the More (“…”) button in the tiny and almost invisible app bar at the bottom right of the screen, and then choose Settings from the app bar menu that appears. In the following screen, Ensure that the setting “Connect to streaming music” is set to On.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ID3 tags to your MP3 files. There's an app called [Music Sense](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=9cb102e1-8926-484d-877e-832316d9ee7f) available in Store that can do that.

1. Install it on your phone, open it, tap on "...", then tap on "My Music".
2. Browse to the song you downloaded and tap "Get Tags" (found below the image placeholder) (Requires Internet).
3. When done, tap "Save" and you're done.

Comment: That app isn't actually available on the store - probably taken down as it facilities downloading music illegally.

Comment: It just unpublished temporarily. Else it must have been removed from the store permanently.

Answer (score 0):

The downloaded songs will be stored by default in `SDcard->Downloads`. Navigate to the folder and move these songs to the location `SDcard->Music`.

This will help the Xbox player to identify the songs easily. You can do this easily by using the [Files](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/apps/files/9wzdncrfj3pl) app.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if this helps, but Xbox Music was replaced with Microsoft Groove Music, Try using that and see if it helps, You will need Windows 10 Mobile OS Installed to use the new app though.